# apply.daily Error: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent in R

Tags: r, apply, xts

It occurs when I use `apply.daily` for an asset that has a total of 10 days worth of intraday data called `rs`

packages needed are:

```
library("xts")
library("highfrequency")
```

Where the error occurs:

```
ts <- apply.daily(rs,function(x){ aggregatets(x ,on="minutes", k=15)})
```

** REPRODUCIBLE DATA **

```
rs <- structure(c(222950, 222880, 222960, 222975, 222800, 222750, 222769, 
222486, 222500, 222660.01, 222829, 222978, 222865, 222855.01, 
222920, 222855, 222711, 222535, 222542, 222750, 222835, 222800, 
222855, 223000, 223000, 223159, 223060, 222940, 222880, 222725.01, 
222900, 222900, 222850, 222813, 222787, 222740, 222820, 222811.63, 
222840, 222676.6301, 222560, 222518, 222871.64, 222886.64, 222979, 
222905, 223095, 223110, 223230, 223309, 223066.63, 223130, 223006.63, 
223000, 223000, 223300, 223261.64, 223261.01, 223291.63, 223366.63, 
223421, 223400, 223366.63, 223480, 223491, 223540, 223500, 223560.01, 
223620.0001, 223980, 223880.05, 223999, 224000, 223760.05, 223880, 
223960, 223921.63, 223814.95, 223775, 223715, 223711.63, 223726.63, 
223801.63, 223591.63, 223651.63, 223500, 223535, 223501.63, 223525, 
223487, 223487, 223460, 223381.63, 223275, 223200, 223085, 223180, 
223300, 223300, 223488.42, 223300, 223460, 223200, 223140, 223150, 
223500, 223249, 223051, 223055, 223051, 223050, 223049, 222940, 
222880, 222860, 222686.01, 222540, 222500, 222500, 222540, 222666, 
222380.05, 222380.1, 222453.42, 222573.42, 222695, 222825.95, 
222954, 222760, 222899.95, 222575, 222684.11, 222560.05, 222630, 
222664, 222867.95, 222978.41, 222950, 223020, 223040, 222935.63, 
222880.05, 222810, 222880, 222885, 222845.64, 222971, 223021, 
222815.63, 222800, 222660, 222795, 222625.01, 222611, 222738.37, 
222663.95, 222879, 222954, 222885, 222489, 222710.64, 222677, 
222680, 222924, 222968, 222997.5, 222919.95, 222800, 222875, 
222980.63, 223001.95, 222800, 222750, 222717.5, 222740.63, 222755.63, 
222800, 222251, 222140, 222250, 222460, 222140, 222420, 222200, 
222240, 222100, 221975, 221980, 221930, 221700, 221814.11, 221650, 
221560, 221493.42, 221560, 221440, 221076, 221200, 221186, 221182, 
221401.71, 221620, 221559, 221619, 221525, 221610, 221440, 221470, 
221400, 221448.37, 221399, 221510, 221425, 221548, 221579, 221680, 
221651, 221515, 221628, 221640, 221659, 221500, 221457, 221677.95, 
221576, 221486, 221480, 221463.41, 221298.42, 221170, 221238.42, 
221055.69, 221355.99, 221180, 221012, 221071, 220940, 220885, 
221060, 220970, 220920, 220800, 220816, 220789, 220850, 220730, 
220839.99, 220734.11, 220920, 220839, 220880, 220800.63, 220888.37, 
221057.11, 221083.4199, 221120, 221240, 221402.37, 221300, 221280, 
221338, 221342.42, 221237.41, 221340, 221265.63, 221200, 221240, 
221120.01, 221250.63, 221314.42, 221315, 221295.63, 221418, 221614.4199, 
221514, 221580, 221634.95, 221494.95, 221410, 221327, 221168.41, 
221168, 220600, 220771, 220880, 220780, 220350, 220250, 220251.05, 
220460, 220550, 219940, 220101, 220100, 220154.99, 220050, 220000, 
220097.99, 220049.99, 219999, 220085, 220101, 220303, 220620, 
220850, 220560, 220550, 220643, 220926, 220900, 220920, 221200, 
221040, 221055, 221117.05, 221260, 221000, 221087, 221166, 221127.42, 
221050, 221091, 220900, 221472, 221580, 221599.95, 221389, 221439, 
221549, 221680, 221777.42, 221750, 221806, 221995.42, 221999.5, 
222000, 221955.63, 222211, 222212, 222520, 222596, 222422, 222563, 
222580, 222541, 222600, 222678, 222601.37, 222469.05, 222556.42, 
222580, 222657, 222701, 222800, 223000, 223000, 222997.5, 222796.41, 
222620.05, 222710.95, 222826.42, 222826.05, 222840, 222853.95, 
222760, 222780, 222795, 222880, 222960, 222800, 222190, 221924, 
221960, 221700, 221650, 221700, 221680, 221724, 221380, 221500, 
221320, 221357.95, 221140, 221080, 221130, 221240, 221124, 221100, 
221036, 221000, 221299.95, 221239.99, 221240, 221138, 221250, 
221295, 221231, 221261, 221258, 221233.01, 221281, 221260, 221231, 
221265.95, 221334, 221254, 221190.63, 221244, 221296.42, 221281.95, 
221244, 221079, 221066, 221131.95, 221132, 221140, 221065, 221117.42, 
221137, 221100, 221040, 221010, 221045, 221020, 221045, 221009.5, 
221055, 221015, 220911, 220945, 220940, 220900, 220973, 220910, 
220955, 220850.63, 220801, 220840.01, 220760.01, 220699.95, 220700.63, 
220720, 220625, 220480, 220490, 220498, 220500, 220452, 220395, 
220310, 220300, 220308.01, 220360, 220320, 220430, 220298.05, 
220436, 220320, 220431, 220365, 220499.99, 220580, 220500, 220495, 
220475, 220510, 220508.5, 220595.63, 220540, 220633.41, 220513.37, 
220520, 220640, 220520, 220648.37, 220518, 220576, 220525, 220458.01, 
220500, 220600, 220531.99, 220475, 220500, 220480, 220580, 220550, 
220540, 220523, 220500.05, 220500, 220440, 220475, 220438, 220499.99, 
220365, 220569.85, 220460, 220634.42, 220560.63, 220645, 220798, 
220740, 220729, 220760, 220770.63, 220780, 220780, 220725, 220742, 
220800, 220789, 220800, 220810, 221000, 221120, 221080, 221205, 
221340, 221321, 221325, 221445, 221600, 221426.2, 221500, 221500, 
221378, 221481, 221795, 221943.95, 221880, 221856, 221670.05, 
222000, 222180, 222200, 222500, 222081.01, 222125, 222480, 222500, 
222480, 222510, 222450.63, 222490, 222300, 222420.05, 222540.63, 
222550, 222550, 222580, 222600, 222732.99, 222600, 222621, 222876, 
222904.42, 222860, 222780.05, 222820, 222966, 222800, 222850, 
222800, 222900, 222920, 223000, 223000, 223000, 223005.63, 223023, 
223088.9999, 222980, 223146, 223190, 223200, 223286.63, 223340, 
223316.63, 223380, 223400, 223500, 223460, 223480, 223400.01, 
223400, 223016.63, 222960.05, 223031.68, 223121.68, 223226.63, 
223256.63, 223166.68, 223406.63, 223451, 223400, 223361.63, 223286.63, 
223531, 223600, 223644.41, 223752, 223815, 223706.63, 223884.37, 
223621, 223764.95, 223854, 223736.68, 223721.64, 223736.68, 223800, 
223743.42, 223736.63, 223751.63, 223800, 223850, 223861, 223924, 
224010, 224000, 224000, 223740, 223721.63, 223708.05, 223700, 
223658, 223540.05, 223599.95, 223496.6301, 223405, 223970, 223900, 
223560, 223520, 222825.69, 223025, 222980, 223296.79, 223123.9335, 
222941, 223020, 223241.63, 223220, 223224, 223295, 223300, 223391, 
223372.41, 223000, 223183, 223250, 223100, 223110, 223365, 223185.63, 
223197, 223145, 223274.99, 223340, 223380, 223437, 223350.64, 
223780, 223689, 223380.63, 223450.01, 223520, 223580, 223520, 
223480, 223450, 223450, 223410, 223450, 223401.42, 223450, 223340, 
223400, 223100, 223194.42, 223120.05, 222995, 222960, 223075, 
223284.41, 222730, 222920, 223000, 223058.63, 222938.63, 223014.42, 
223119, 223179.85, 223103.63, 223133.63, 223420, 223000, 222800, 
222884, 222501, 222530, 222237, 222250, 222275, 222220, 222421, 
222490.95, 222350, 222400, 222699.37, 222759.42, 222925.05, 222890, 
222855, 222745, 222840.01, 222540, 222499, 222599.95, 222405, 
222460, 222420, 222455, 222420, 222455, 222430, 222430, 222552.63, 
222672.63, 222561, 222600, 222575.01, 222560, 222476, 222500, 
222215, 222255.05, 222236, 222195, 222162.63, 222277, 222180, 
222000, 222035, 222000, 222235, 222228, 222220, 222240.05, 222415, 
222415, 222365, 222365, 222320, 222440, 222510, 222250, 222180, 
222100, 222060, 222160, 222105, 222000, 221500, 221394.99, 220887, 
220860, 221220, 221140, 221150, 221141.95, 221395, 221600, 221665, 
221914.05, 221980, 221825, 221800, 221689, 221660, 221639.42, 
221637, 221800, 221590, 221625, 221625, 221600, 221504, 221455, 
221470.63, 221475, 221360, 221450, 221729, 221660.01, 221779.37, 
221851, 221778, 221674.42, 221770, 221765, 221953, 221800, 221890.63, 
221870, 221875.63, 221859.42, 221760, 221662.63, 221784.42, 221761, 
221722.01, 221700, 221731.42, 221650, 221785, 221817, 221739.95, 
221894.42, 221940, 221905, 221857.63, 221829, 221614, 221745, 
221708, 221500, 221500, 221500, 221360, 221400, 221565.99, 221313.42, 
221343.99, 221213.99, 221090, 221178.42, 221120, 221261, 221321, 
221285, 221160, 221259.37, 221150, 221050, 221020, 221047.63, 
221229.42), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", index = structure(c(1424215944, 
1424216030, 1424216096, 1424216129, 1424216170, 1424216269, 1424216304, 
1424216380, 1424216407, 1424216511, 1424216568, 1424216592, 1424216647, 
1424216768, 1424216835, 1424216905, 1424217305, 1424217518, 1424217589, 
1424217639, 1424217662, 1424217827, 1424217947, 1424218277, 1424218321, 
1424218396, 1424218540, 1424218585, 1424218623, 1424218825, 1424219502, 
1424219668, 1424219786, 1424219862, 1424219982, 1424220087, 1424220324, 
1424220581, 1424220658, 1424220890, 1424220985, 1424221510, 1424223299, 
1424223415, 1424223960, 1424224084, 1424224848, 1424224953, 1424225000, 
1424225365, 1424225644, 1424225743, 1424225879, 1424225937, 1424226051, 
1424226706, 1424226732, 1424227159, 1424227758, 1424227848, 1424228244, 
1424228334, 1424228632, 1424228693, 1424228887, 1424229004, 1424229124, 
1424229247, 1424229311, 1424230060, 1424230216, 1424230368, 1424230407, 
1424230521, 1424231487, 1424231750, 1424231974, 1424232574, 1424233279, 
1424233672, 1424233817, 1424234063, 1424234195, 1424234661, 1424235035, 
1424235224, 1424235405, 1424235480, 1424235650, 1424235719, 1424236094, 
1424237223, 1424237343, 1424237724, 1424238079, 1424238871, 1424238928, 
1424239078, 1424239130, 1424239165, 1424239242, 1424302231, 1424302371, 
1424302423, 1424302467, 1424302544, 1424302853, 1424302925, 1424303099, 
1424303105, 1424303246, 1424303431, 1424303641, 1424303905, 1424303990, 
1424304064, 1424304777, 1424304848, 1424304924, 1424305052, 1424305201, 
1424305381, 1424305542, 1424305696, 1424305803, 1424306199, 1424306427, 
1424306540, 1424306616, 1424306875, 1424307950, 1424308235, 1424308349, 
1424308785, 1424309059, 1424309620, 1424310130, 1424310376, 1424310808, 
1424310847, 1424311667, 1424311695, 1424312035, 1424312310, 1424312754, 
1424312898, 1424312982, 1424313273, 1424313599, 1424313777, 1424314828, 
1424315009, 1424315752, 1424315789, 1424316672, 1424317028, 1424318445, 
1424319424, 1424320039, 1424320715, 1424321205, 1424321812, 1424321887, 
1424322057, 1424322092, 1424322435, 1424323149, 1424323313, 1424323476, 
1424323749, 1424323844, 1424324372, 1424324748, 1424325059, 1424325351, 
1424325368, 1424325576, 1424388694, 1424388741, 1424388786, 1424388882, 
1424388955, 1424388981, 1424389070, 1424389098, 1424389602, 1424389674, 
1424389713, 1424389797, 1424390183, 1424390480, 1424390572, 1424390728, 
1424390977, 1424391048, 1424391150, 1424391239, 1424391402, 1424391473, 
1424391583, 1424391924, 1424392530, 1424392835, 1424392976, 1424393570, 
1424393597, 1424393995, 1424394158, 1424394241, 1424394334, 1424394567, 
1424394817, 1424395154, 1424395267, 1424395561, 1424395844, 1424396032, 
1424396119, 1424396171, 1424396399, 1424396422, 1424396614, 1424396655, 
1424396758, 1424397059, 1424397066, 1424397176, 1424397413, 1424397816, 
1424398019, 1424398027, 1424398229, 1424398865, 1424399060, 1424399456, 
1424399463, 1424399755, 1424399771, 1424400029, 1424400710, 1424400910, 
1424401326, 1424401694, 1424401911, 1424401974, 1424402119, 1424402253, 
1424402307, 1424402503, 1424402537, 1424402601, 1424403048, 1424403143, 
1424403438, 1424403662, 1424404268, 1424404486, 1424404981, 1424405338, 
1424405395, 1424405797, 1424405824, 1424406072, 1424406687, 1424406754, 
1424407281, 1424407331, 1424407396, 1424407644, 1424408005, 1424408263, 
1424408421, 1424409284, 1424409565, 1424409658, 1424410207, 1424410553, 
1424410782, 1424411036, 1424411043, 1424411493, 1424411565, 1424475109, 
1424475187, 1424475493, 1424475576, 1424475640, 1424475689, 1424475806, 
1424475914, 1424476016, 1424476716, 1424477302, 1424477897, 1424478015, 
1424478107, 1424478149, 1424478523, 1424478570, 1424478617, 1424478735, 
1424478809, 1424479004, 1424479235, 1424479278, 1424479354, 1424479404, 
1424479517, 1424479590, 1424479630, 1424480045, 1424481224, 1424481283, 
1424481587, 1424482091, 1424484363, 1424484834, 1424485111, 1424485599, 
1424485721, 1424485784, 1424485807, 1424485927, 1424486120, 1424486587, 
1424486753, 1424487230, 1424487274, 1424487912, 1424488251, 1424488357, 
1424488744, 1424488957, 1424489506, 1424489752, 1424489778, 1424489928, 
1424490090, 1424491105, 1424491697, 1424491861, 1424492168, 1424492391, 
1424492972, 1424493098, 1424493293, 1424493379, 1424493636, 1424493662, 
1424493821, 1424493975, 1424494022, 1424494274, 1424494549, 1424494930, 
1424494997, 1424495101, 1424495845, 1424496167, 1424496524, 1424497015, 
1424497371, 1424497525, 1424497850, 1424498103, 1424498190, 1424498268, 
1424498335, 1424498383, 1424734224, 1424734297, 1424734372, 1424734406, 
1424734526, 1424734581, 1424734679, 1424734709, 1424734773, 1424735143, 
1424735271, 1424735425, 1424735816, 1424735853, 1424736056, 1424736112, 
1424736140, 1424736289, 1424736334, 1424736407, 1424736495, 1424736643, 
1424736789, 1424737016, 1424737021, 1424737316, 1424737333, 1424737475, 
1424737510, 1424737687, 1424737759, 1424738127, 1424738258, 1424738377, 
1424738534, 1424738689, 1424738742, 1424739030, 1424739345, 1424739395, 
1424739570, 1424739788, 1424740254, 1424740366, 1424740840, 1424740952, 
1424741028, 1424741123, 1424741203, 1424741352, 1424741404, 1424741517, 
1424741536, 1424741759, 1424741802, 1424741875, 1424741933, 1424742469, 
1424742730, 1424743317, 1424743423, 1424743532, 1424743564, 1424743837, 
1424744155, 1424744165, 1424744243, 1424744618, 1424744817, 1424744832, 
1424745064, 1424745175, 1424745220, 1424745255, 1424745569, 1424745615, 
1424745958, 1424745981, 1424746167, 1424746340, 1424746955, 1424747131, 
1424747204, 1424747271, 1424747419, 1424747525, 1424747663, 1424747853, 
1424748027, 1424748162, 1424748562, 1424748700, 1424748729, 1424749053, 
1424749386, 1424749482, 1424749548, 1424749674, 1424750566, 1424750595, 
1424750827, 1424751165, 1424751455, 1424751867, 1424752039, 1424752179, 
1424752357, 1424752437, 1424752440, 1424752634, 1424752846, 1424753182, 
1424753231, 1424753513, 1424753563, 1424753589, 1424753879, 1424753913, 
1424753949, 1424754056, 1424754076, 1424754282, 1424754333, 1424754408, 
1424754423, 1424754538, 1424755338, 1424755811, 1424755944, 1424756039, 
1424756059, 1424756138, 1424756256, 1424756287, 1424756579, 1424756613, 
1424756752, 1424756782, 1424756886, 1424757045, 1424757087, 1424757358, 
1424757378, 1424757420, 1424757521, 1424757598, 1424820657, 1424820739, 
1424820805, 1424820973, 1424821031, 1424821132, 1424821207, 1424821573, 
1424821631, 1424821698, 1424821756, 1424821814, 1424821945, 1424822106, 
1424822261, 1424822325, 1424822409, 1424822537, 1424822932, 1424822982, 
1424823000, 1424823274, 1424823475, 1424823576, 1424823838, 1424823953, 
1424823995, 1424824071, 1424824184, 1424824557, 1424824599, 1424824677, 
1424824846, 1424824971, 1424824991, 1424825136, 1424825200, 1424825293, 
1424825378, 1424825428, 1424825797, 1424826272, 1424826340, 1424826594, 
1424826715, 1424826957, 1424827126, 1424827253, 1424827610, 1424827796, 
1424827846, 1424827915, 1424827928, 1424828258, 1424828393, 1424828571, 
1424828631, 1424828671, 1424829304, 1424829371, 1424829596, 1424829962, 
1424830125, 1424830154, 1424830315, 1424830363, 1424830721, 1424830854, 
1424831035, 1424831095, 1424831210, 1424831503, 1424832338, 1424832437, 
1424832521, 1424832654, 1424832750, 1424832809, 1424832936, 1424832994, 
1424833179, 1424833204, 1424833689, 1424833907, 1424833945, 1424834209, 
1424834554, 1424834860, 1424835130, 1424835203, 1424835492, 1424835696, 
1424835884, 1424835909, 1424837732, 1424838132, 1424838295, 1424839733, 
1424840006, 1424840058, 1424840137, 1424840550, 1424840945, 1424841098, 
1424841259, 1424841417, 1424841425, 1424842031, 1424842205, 1424842262, 
1424843354, 1424843493, 1424843528, 1424843656, 1424843874, 1424843990, 
1424907030, 1424907068, 1424907211, 1424907443, 1424907999, 1424908024, 
1424908192, 1424908288, 1424908363, 1424909228, 1424909429, 1424909594, 
1424911146, 1424911251, 1424911838, 1424911921, 1424911983, 1424912558, 
1424913086, 1424914112, 1424914638, 1424915020, 1424915059, 1424915300, 
1424917090, 1424917171, 1424917763, 1424917983, 1424918342, 1424918916, 
1424919945, 1424920844, 1424922582, 1424923195, 1424923539, 1424923583, 
1424924054, 1424924172, 1424924665, 1424925319, 1424925398, 1424925599, 
1424925639, 1424925701, 1424925938, 1424926029, 1424926124, 1424926157, 
1424926254, 1424926284, 1424926636, 1424927060, 1424927190, 1424927575, 
1424927618, 1424928595, 1424928615, 1424929324, 1424929465, 1424929675, 
1424929686, 1424929873, 1424929928, 1424930024, 1424930266, 1424993572, 
1424993681, 1424993785, 1424994221, 1424994512, 1424994703, 1424996027, 
1424996130, 1424996283, 1424996799, 1424997350, 1424997369, 1424998229, 
1424998363, 1424998950, 1424999130, 1424999888, 1425000287, 1425000943, 
1425001183, 1425001429, 1425002818, 1425003021, 1425003318, 1425003587, 
1425004092, 1425004163, 1425004769, 1425004825, 1425004903, 1425005062, 
1425005185, 1425005257, 1425005319, 1425005609, 1425006152, 1425006206, 
1425006522, 1425006546, 1425006812, 1425007290, 1425007580, 1425007985, 
1425008279, 1425010559, 1425011158, 1425011352, 1425013245, 1425013319, 
1425013453, 1425015052, 1425015475, 1425015529, 1425015631, 1425015779, 
1425015900, 1425015998, 1425016047, 1425016339, 1425016573, 1425016666, 
1425016843, 1425079818, 1425079915, 1425079968, 1425080031, 1425080075, 
1425080143, 1425080288, 1425080521, 1425080636, 1425080661, 1425080952, 
1425081073, 1425081300, 1425081476, 1425081532, 1425082363, 1425082845, 
1425083334, 1425083440, 1425083681, 1425083767, 1425083869, 1425084024, 
1425084170, 1425084191, 1425084312, 1425084836, 1425084931, 1425085220, 
1425085291, 1425085459, 1425085805, 1425086132, 1425086324, 1425086453, 
1425086475, 1425087531, 1425087656, 1425087729, 1425087857, 1425087997, 
1425088231, 1425088848, 1425090115, 1425091120, 1425091288, 1425091438, 
1425091440, 1425091568, 1425091891, 1425092023, 1425092221, 1425092280, 
1425092754, 1425092901, 1425092992, 1425093175, 1425093403, 1425093689, 
1425093905, 1425094284, 1425095849, 1425096057, 1425096303, 1425097383, 
1425098101, 1425098394, 1425098431, 1425098668, 1425099478, 1425099507, 
1425099656, 1425099777, 1425099873, 1425100187, 1425100552, 1425101205, 
1425101884, 1425102057, 1425102080, 1425102228, 1425102312, 1425102525, 
1425102561, 1425102752, 1425102792, 1425102879, 1425102997, 1425103039, 
1425103094, 1425103190), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), .Dim = c(849L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "x.Close"))
```

Comment: @ExperimenteR what do you mean? Is there a problem with the reproducible data?

Comment: @ExperimenteR I have to use `aggregatets()` from `highfrequency` because if I use `aggregate.ts()` when I later try to combine the results via: `hm <- do.call("rbind", ts)` will return a non-timeSeries object

Comment: non-timeseries object is not convertible to xts object?

Comment: @Khashaa not sure how to do that? maybe `reclass()` ... but don;t know how to do that with my `do.call` FUN: `hm <- do.call("rbind", ts)`

Comment: This might not be the proper way. How about `l <- split.xts(rs, f="days"); do.call("rbind", lapply(l, function(x){ aggregatets(x ,on="minutes", k=15)}))`. Does it work as expected?

Comment: @Khashaa looks correct to me! Why do you say it is not the proper way? & also do you know what the cause is for the error? You can post as a comment so I can accept your answer!

Comment: Just a wild guess:`period.apply` often assumes a single valued function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split `rs` by days, apply `aggregatets` on them and `rbind`

```
l <- split.xts(rs, f="days")
ts <- do.call("rbind", lapply(l, function(x){ aggregatets(x ,on="minutes", k=15)}))
```